# Access Denied - CloudFront + Django Compressor

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, django-compressor

Just started using django compressor along with my AWS/Cloudfront setup on Heroku.

Having an issue on my local machine where the compressed CSS and JS files are not loading for the page and when i view the source (CSS Example)

It is showing as “Access Denied”

https://d3dycr1vdfv0cd.cloudfront.net/static/CACHE/css/50c1fe094e5d.css

I thought this might be a permissions issue on my S3 bucket and clicked on “Make Public” on my CSS folder in S3.  But still no luck.

any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? We are having the same